# Add location points on a choropleth map in python

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have already created a choropleth map using Plotly(go.Choropleth) based on the density of that area.
Now I want to add location points on the map, how should I do that? 
The location points are national parks that I want to plot on the choropleth map, and they’re in another dataframe.

Comment: Please, provide code, data, and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and about [mcve](/help/mcve).